# r script produce output as nothing

Tags: r

I am recently learning r script for a requirement, when I try to run this script with sample data, it gives me 0 columns and 0 rows as result. I am not sure what could be the reason. Can anyone point me what is wrong with the script?

```
clinAct<- data.frame(
`Pr # Required Subj`= 1:5,
'Pr # enrolled'= as.Date(c("2010-01-05", "2019-01-07", "2020-01-03", "2010-01-04", "2020-01-05")),
'Pr L Subj Enr Exp'= as.Date(c("2021-03-30","2021-03-30","2021-02-09", "2010-01-04", "2020-01-05"))
)

target <- function() {
  first_column <- data.frame(
    Date = clinAct$`Pr L Subj Enr Exp`,
    `# Required Total` = clinAct$`Pr # Required Subj`,
    check.names = F
    )
  return(list(first_column))
  }

target()
```

Comment: The names you use for your data frame inside the function are incorrect. Check `names(clinAct)`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, data.frame is "repairing" your column names to remove whitespace and special characters. You can check this easily.

```
> colnames(clinAct)
[1] "Pr...Required.Subj" "Pr...enrolled"      "Pr.L.Subj.Enr.Exp"
```

Either you adapt the code in your function to the changed colnames, or - if you really need to retain the colnames in the format that you have specified above - you set `check.names = F` when setting `clinAct` the same way you already do in your function when defining `first_column`.

That being said, I don't really see what you're trying to do there, but I suspect you might be able to work a little more elegantly with `dplyr` :)